# How do I switch mates?

Tags: tokyo-jungle

I ran too close to a potential mate and now she's following me, but I wanted to mate with a different pom. Surely there's some way to swap to a better mate when available, no?

Comment: `Surely there's some way to swap to a better mate when available, no?` If only... Oh, if only....

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the only way to switch mates would be to get your current mate killed. That's a lot harder than it sounds...so you might as well just stick it out and try for a better mate next generation.